# Direct Collocation not Inferring Continuous Time States

Tags: drake

I am working on a trajectory optimization problem for a ball to get from point A to point B on a plane. Direct collocation was working fine before I added obstacles. However, I updated the code to connect a MultibodyPlant with a SceneGraph in the following code:

```
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder=builder, time_step=0) 
    parser = Parser(plant)
    ConfigureParser(parser)
    parser.AddModelsFromString(minigolf_urdf, 'urdf')
    plant.Finalize()

    diagram = builder.Build()
    diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
    dircol = DirectCollocation(
        plant,
        plant_context,
        num_time_samples=41,
        minimum_timestep=0.1,
        maximum_timestep=1,
        input_port_index=plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index(),
    )
```

but now I am running into the following error:

`RuntimeError: This system doesn't have any continuous states. DirectCollocation only makes sense for systems with continuous-time dynamics.`

I thought defining plant with `time_step = 0` would make the system continuous so I'm not sure why the program thinks there are no continuous states.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised by the error message. Is there a chance you don't actually have any states in that urdf? (if you do have states and you send me your code, I would love to look into it).  But there are a few things to know about your current approach:

1. If the `plant` needs the `scenegraph` to compute its dynamics (are there any collision dynamics?), then you should pass the `diagram` into `DirectCollocation`, not just the `plant`.
2. If you do have collision dynamics, then we would normally simulate them with `MultibodyPlant` in discrete-time mode.  There is a chance that continuous-time will work ok for you, but I would try to verify that with some simple simulations of your plant.
3. Doing `DirectCollocation` through the contact without splitting up the modes might be a difficult problem for the optimizers (discontinuities in the optimization landscape, etc).